# Attributes not showing up in json, restructure json objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

Original json data:

```
{
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": "",
  "Implementations": [
    {
      "BirthDate": "",
      "UniqueTraits": "",
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male",
        "PlaceOfBirth": "",
        "Weight": "",
        "Height": "",
        "EyeColor": ""
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female",
        "PlaceOfBirth": "",
        "Weight": "",
        "Height": "",
        "EyeColor": ""
      },
      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",
          "Name": "ABCD",
          "County": "East"
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",
          "Name": "ABCD",
          "County": "West"
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "EFGH",
          "County": "East"
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "EFGH",
          "County": "West"
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "IJKL"
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ],
      "Boy": [
        {
          "AgeGroup": "A",
          "Id": 1,
          "MaternalName": "",
          "PaternalName": ""
        },
        {
          "AgeGroup": "B",
          "Id": 2,
          "MaternalName": "",
          "PaternalName": ""
        },
        {
          "AgeGroup": "C",
          "Id": 3,
          "MaternalName": "",
          "PaternalName": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Negative"
    }
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",
  "CommonTwo": "",
  "EatingHabits": {
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {
    "Type": "Fast"
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {},
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}
```

Expected json response:

```
  {
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": "",
  "Implementations": [
    {
      "BirthDate": "",
      "UniqueTraits": "",
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male",
        "PlaceOfBirth": "",
        "Weight": "",
        "Height": "",
        "EyeColor": "",
        "Country": [
          {
            "Orientation": "Male",
            "Name": "ABCD"
          }
        ],
        "EastCounty": {
          "Orientation": "Male",
          "Name": "ABCD",
          "County": "East"
        },
        "State": [
          {
            "Address": "XYZ Street",
            "ZipCode": "US"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female",
        "PlaceOfBirth": "",
        "Weight": "",
        "Height": "",
        "EyeColor": "",
        "Country": [
          {
            "Orientation": "Female",
            "Name": "EFGH"
          },
          {
            "Orientation": "Female",
            "Name": "IJKL"
          }
        ],
        "EastCounty": {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "EFGH",
          "County": "East"
        },
        "State": [
          {
            "Address": "XYZ Street",
            "ZipCode": "US"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Girl": [
        {
          "AgeGroup": "A",
          "identification": [
            {
              "Number": 1,
              "MaternalName": "",
              "PaternalName": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "AgeGroup": "B",
          "identification": [
            {
              "Number": 1,
              "MaternalName": "",
              "PaternalName": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "AgeGroup": "C",
          "identification": [
            {
              "Number": 1,
              "MaternalName": "",
              "PaternalName": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Negative"
    }
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",
  "CommonTwo": "",
  "EatingHabits": {
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {
    "Type": "Fast"
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {},
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}
```

Questions:

I have three specific questions:

1) How do I retain the attributes that are directly under "Male" and "Female" and also before "Male"? After I run my program these attributes are not shown in my response.

I want to retain attributes like

```
"BirthDate":"", 
"UniqueTraits": "" AND 

"Gender": "Male", 
"PlaceOfBirth": "", 
"Weight": "", 
"Height": "", 
"EyeColor": ""
```

exactly as in my original and expected json data.

2) How do I add another EastCounty{} after Country[] both in Male and Female based on "County": East and Orientation? Please refer the original and expected json for reference.

3) How do I restructure Boy[] in original json to the new structure exactly as is shown in Girl[] in expected json response? Note "Id" in Boy[] changes to "Number" in Girl.So if there are multiple "identification" in either of the "AgeGroup" then "Number" would change sequentially for every record.

Current program:

```
function modifyImplementations(Implementations) {
  var finalResult = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < Implementations.Implementations.length; i++) {
    var currentImplementation = Implementations.Implementations[i];
    var targetObj = {
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Country": [],
        "State": currentImplementation.State
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": [],
        "State": currentImplementation.State
      }
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < currentImplementation.Country.length; j++) {
      var currentCountry = currentImplementation.Country[j];
      if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Male') {
        targetObj.Male.Country.push(currentCountry);
      } else if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Female') {
        targetObj.Female.Country.push(currentCountry);
      }
    }
    finalResult.push(targetObj);
  }
  return finalResult
}

var x = Object.assign({}, Implementations);
x.Implementations = modifyImplementations(Implementations);

console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Comment: As you've asked in case of large number of attributes which are to be preserved, then in the place where you're creating targetObj instead of creating a new object clone currentImplementation into a new object and make changes on it like add country/state/county and finally remove country/state arrays from cloned obj and push all those back to finalResult, this way you'll only work on needed fields !!

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am not able to see the cloned object in the console. 
  for (var i = 0; i < Implementations.Implementations.length; i++) {
    var currentImplementation = Implementations.Implementations[i];
 
 var originalObject = Object.assign({}, currentApplication); 
 console.log(x);
    /*var targetObj = {
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Country": [],
        "State": currentImplementation.State
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": [],
        "State": currentImplementation.State
      }
    };*/

Comment: It's not  var originalObject = Object.assign({}, currentApplication), change this to :  var originalObject = Object.assign({}, currentImplementation) also just directly assign like : let originalObject = currentImplementation; Make sure at this point :: var x = Object.assign({}, Implementations);
x.Implementations = modifyImplementations(Implementations);

console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

Node.Js waits for x.Implementations = modifyImplementations(Implementations); to complete before printing console.log as Node.Js is asynchronous make sure to check that !!

Comment: I have updated what I have so far since I am unable to add in the comment box. How do I verify if the cloned object is copied correctly?

Comment: ok as a suggestion, if you use vscode as your IDE, then try to use quokka extension which will be really helpful for run-time analyzation of code, all you need is to open quokka tab (cmd+shift+p) will open a new js file and then paste your code & make sure there are no errors, use few console.logs for quick checks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working function which would produce expected result, Please do some refactoring as certainly there are better ways to implement in few areas of code, just quickly done all your needs here to produce expected o/p and also your question needs to be updated with valid JSON's :

```
function modifyImplementations(Implementations) {

    for (let i = 0; i < Implementations.Implementations.length; i++) {
        let currentImplementation = Implementations.Implementations[i];

        currentImplementation['Male']['Country'] = []
        currentImplementation['Female']['Country'] = []
        currentImplementation['Male']['EastCounty'] = []
        currentImplementation['Female']['EastCounty'] = []
        currentImplementation['Male']['State'] = currentImplementation['State'];
        currentImplementation['Female']['State'] = currentImplementation['State'];

        for (let j = 0; j < currentImplementation.Country.length; j++) {
            let currentCountry = currentImplementation.Country[j];
            let currentCountryObj = {}
            if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Male') {
                if (currentCountry.County && currentCountry.County == "East") {
                    currentCountryObj['County'] = currentCountry.County
                    currentCountryObj['Name'] = currentCountry.Name
                    currentCountryObj['Orientation'] = currentCountry.Orientation
                    currentImplementation['Male']['EastCounty'].push(currentCountryObj)
                } else {
                    currentCountryObj['Name'] = currentCountry.Name
                    currentCountryObj['Orientation'] = currentCountry.Orientation
                    currentImplementation['Male']['Country'].push(currentCountryObj);
                }
            } else if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Female') {
                if (currentCountry.County && currentCountry.County == "East") {
                    currentCountryObj['County'] = currentCountry.County
                    currentCountryObj['Name'] = currentCountry.Name
                    currentCountryObj['Orientation'] = currentCountry.Orientation
                    currentImplementation['Female']['EastCounty'].push(currentCountryObj)
                } else {
                    currentCountryObj['Name'] = currentCountry.Name
                    currentCountryObj['Orientation'] = currentCountry.Orientation
                    currentImplementation['Female']['Country'].push(currentCountryObj);
                }
            }
        }
        delete currentImplementation['Country']
        delete currentImplementation['State']

        let mapObj = [];
        for (items of currentImplementation.Boy) {
            let objs = currentImplementation.Boy.filter((obj) => {
                return items.AgeGroup === obj.AgeGroup
            })
            mapObj.push(objs)
            currentImplementation.Boy = currentImplementation.Boy.filter(e => e.AgeGroup !== items.AgeGroup);
        }

        let finalArray = mapObj.filter(e => e.length > 0)
        currentImplementation['Girl'] = []
        for (anArray of finalArray) {
            let finalObj = {}
            finalObj.identification = [];
            if (anArray.length && anArray.length > 1) {
                let number = 1
                for (oneObj of anArray) {
                    let objs = {};
                    objs['Number'] = number
                    objs['MaternalName'] = oneObj['MaternalName']
                    objs['PaternalName'] = oneObj['PaternalName']
                    number += 1
                    finalObj['AgeGroup'] = oneObj.AgeGroup
                    finalObj.identification.push(objs);
                }
            } else if (anArray.length == 1) {
                let objs = {};
                finalObj['AgeGroup'] = anArray[0].AgeGroup
                objs = {};
                objs['Number'] = 1
                objs['MaternalName'] = anArray[0]['MaternalName']
                objs['PaternalName'] = anArray[0]['PaternalName']
                finalObj.identification.push(objs);
            }
            currentImplementation['Girl'].push(finalObj)
            delete currentImplementation['Boy']
        }
    }
    return Implementations
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.The above code should definitely work. My only issue is when attributes are of a large number, in that case, adding all the attributes in targetObj would be too dense. Instead, is there a way we can push the attributes before and after "Male" {} or can it be printed in a different way in the console log to get the attributes without adding every attribute in the targetObj?I would definitely have to consider the edge case when there are large number of attributes.

Comment: @Eva : Updated answer as per latest comments & your question has many sub questions in it and needs sometime to code/refactor your code for all scenarios plus go ahead with your coding and let us know where exactly you're stuck. let's wrap it up rather than thinking on performance factors at this moment..

Comment: Appreciate your efforts in helping me, thank you for promptly answering my questions. With the updated answer and a little refactoring to append the section from Personality Traits to the bottom, I am able to see the attributes before and after "Male".However, EastCounty{} is empty in my response and throws an exception at originalObject['Male']['EastCounty'].push(currentCountryObj). Is it beacuse the way it is declared in the original object?

Comment: I've tested that code & it should be working, Can you give me the error or give me the code lemme check if there is an issue that I can quickly fix..

Comment: You are right,  it will only take array for the push function to be valid which is originalObject['Male']['EastCounty'] = [].It is not throwing any error and I see data inside 'EastCounty'. However, json response is EastCounty[] in my response since it is declared as an array in the originalObject.  The expected json response is 'EastCounty' {}(curly brackets) which is not  an array. Is there a way we can still use push function if we declare it as   originalObject['Male']['EastCounty'] = {} which is what I changed and got the error "push is not a valid function." Hope my explanation helps!

Comment: I was aware of it that it should be an object,I've made it an array because if we've multiple countries with county as east then what you'll see in 'EastCounty' is the last one from the loop, So we're pushing multiple 'County= East' to an array. If you're sure that there will only be one object in countries with county = 'East' then you can have  'EastCounty' = {} . So now, remove declarations of originalObject['Male']['EastCounty'] = [] and at the position of originalObject['Male']['EastCounty'].push(currentCountryObj) replace that with originalObject['Male']['EastCounty'] = currentCountryObj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196947/discussion-between-srinivas-y-and-eva).

Comment: after updating the answer where we do not create an object I no longer get the expected result. Also now it throws an error at Boy not defined since we do not have an object created.

Comment: @Eva, Did you take the above code from answer ? Can you please ping in chat room more about the issue.

Comment: I did update it with updated code I still get Boy not defined error. please take a look at my comments in chat room